# galleria php script to load all pics in folder

Tags: php, html, galleria

Hi am having trouble figuring this out as I'm fairly new to php got it to open the `dir` but now I'm having trouble with the `getimagesize()` function here is the code

```
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
http-equiv="content-type">
<title>Photo-Album Paul Bange Roofing</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery /1/jquery.js">                                                                   </script>
<script src="galleria-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<style>
#galleria{ width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #000; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="galleria"><?php
$directory = "images";
$handle = openDir($directory); 
while ($file = readDir($handle)) { 
if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && !is_dir($file)) {
if (strstr($file, ".gif") ||
 strstr($file, ".png") ||
 strstr($file, ".jpg")) {
$directory_file = $directory . $file;
$info = getImageSize($directory_file);
echo "<img src=\"$directory_file\"";
echo " width=\"$info[0]\" height=\"$info[1]\"> <br>\n";
}
}
}
closeDir($handle);
?>
</div>
<script>
Galleria.loadTheme('themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
Galleria.configure({
transition: 'fadeslide',
fullscreenDoubleTap: true,
imageCrop: false,
trueFullscreen: true,
imagePan: true,
responsive: true,
swipe: true,
imagePosition: 'center',
showInfo: true,
fullscreenCrop: 'landscape',
initialTransition: 'fade'


});

Galleria.ready(function() {
this.bind('image', function(e) {
    $(e.imageTarget).bind('contextmenu', function(f) {
        f.preventDefault();

        return false;
    }).bind('dragstart', function(f) {

        return false;
    });;
    });
});

Galleria.run('#galleria');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the error im getting is:

> Warning: getimagesize(images20140509_135116.jpg) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home4/downsys/public_html/galleria/paulbange/index.php on line 22

i get the same error for every pic its trying to load

you can see whats going on at www.allwhite.com/galleria/paulbange/index.php

Comment: The error is fairly clear. Is your path correct?

Comment: the path has to be correct cause its the only way the script will even open the dir to read the images in it otherwise i get a opendir.function error

Comment: Are the files in the directory you indicate?

Comment: yes it is  trying to load all the images, even shows the filename of the images but then says no such file or dir I dont get it tried everything i can think of

Comment: ive changed file permissions and indexed the dir still nothing

Comment: PHP is generally pretty smart. If it says the file doesn't exist then it is a safe bet the file doesn't exist.

Comment: but now the question is why does php think the file doesn't exist when its showing the filename with the getimagesize.function no such file or dir

Comment: Which line is line 22?

Comment: $info = getImageSize($directory_file);

Comment: What is the actual directory it states?

Comment: $directory = "images";

Comment: if you echo `$directory_file` after `$directory` and `$file` get concatenated, what do you get? My bet is that it is missing something.

Comment: ok so the string is missing something directory . file im lost

Comment: What do you see when you echo out `$directory_file`? Can you post it here?

Comment: Anything? What did the echo return?

Comment: Wow.  Nobody sees that's he just missing a slash between images and 20140509....  (images20140509_135116.jpg vs images/20140509_135116.jpg)?  http://www.allwhite.com/galleria/paulbange/images/20140509_135116.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Simple missing slash in the directory.  Change:

```
$directory_file = $directory . $file;
```

to

```
$directory_file = $directory .'/'. $file;
```